# Use/Purpose of beans in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**Could someone give an overview or a summary of what the purpose of beans in a Spring framework context?**

I understand the standard Java bean (no arg constructor, getters/setters, often serialized), but the Spring bean purpose seems to be different.

Is it a way of implementing the Singleton design pattern (one instance, for like factory classes) in a *simple, reusable* fashion?

I've mainly used Spring with **annotations**, but I feel I need to grasp this in order to understand Spring.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657168/spring-should-every-class-in-my-project-be-a-bean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand the standard Java bean (no arg constructor,
>   getters/setters, often serialized), but the Spring bean purpose seems
>   to be different.

You mean *always* serialized.  Why do you think the purpose seems different?

In the end, you write classes.  A lot of time these are POJOs, Plain Old Java Objects.  Sometimes you implement an interface or extend a class, but its all just classes.

Beans are just classes.  Don't overcomplicate it.

Now Spring might take your beans (classes) and manage them for you via any of a number of policies (prototype, singleton) but that doesn't change what a bean is, it speaks to how Spring *manages* the bean.

Comment: I see. I guess what I need to understand as well is how Spring manages them (in a higher level sense) and what are the advantages/use cases of these policies that do so. 

That said, that doesn't seem to be something that can be put into a answer/question, and something that I should discover on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-introduction

Answer (score 8):

Beans are objects that form the backbone of the application.

A bean is **simply an object** that is **instantiated**, **assembled** and otherwise **managed** by a **Spring IoC container**; other than that, there is nothing special about a bean.It is in all other respects one of probably many objects in your application.

Spring beans are defined in a spring configuration file or by using annotations, instantiated by the Spring container, and then injected into your application.

Spring beans will not be singleton design pattern until you explicitly make them to be.The **singleton design pattern** and the **spring scope 'singleton'** are **different** things.You can define different bean scopes depending on your requirements.

The scopes could be :

1. singleton – Return a single bean instance per Spring IoC container
2. prototype – Return a new bean instance each time when requested
3. request – Return a single bean instance per HTTP request.
4. session – Return a single bean instance per HTTP session.
5. globalSession – Return a single bean instance per global HTTP
   session.

The default scope is singleton.

Answer (score 4):

To understand best, you should get familiar with **dependency injection**. In a few words dependency injection allows you to use objects, or services without explicitly creating them (of course, it gives other benefits, but let's focus on the question). This is achieved by maintaining a **dependency container** that is - roughly said - a collection of beans.

A bean is a service/component you use in your application. Unlike the EJB, with Spring the bean is not constrained to constructor arguments or specific annotations (especially if you use xml contexts). You register a bean with a container (by defining a context), and when you require it, the container will provide you with an instance of that bean. In order to create the bean, the container examines its class and constructors, and uses any other registered beans within that context, to call the appropriate constructor or property setter.

You can configure a bean to be a **singleton** - this is **not** a singleton as in the design pattern term. Singleton beans are created once **within the container**, and the same instance is used whenever the bean is requested from that container. You can also use the **prototype** scope to force the container to create a new instance each time.