# spring - should every class in my project be a bean?

Tags: spring, javabeans

In my project there are several @repositories , @Services, @Controllers

My question is for the other 99% of the classes:

Should i declare them as beans as well?

pros\cons?

thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beans are a way of wiring together the larger components of an application. Not every object or class is a large component. Consider the `String` class,  for example.  So the answer is *no*.